# Elmah not logging exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, elmah

In my MVC web project. I am trying to show custom error pages to my visitors without using "custromerrors" element in web.config.

I can catch exceptions like below

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

    bool success = RaiseErrorSignal(exception);

    Response.Clear();

    HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

    RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");

    if (httpException == null)
    {
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
    }
    else //It's an Http Exception, Let's handle it.
    {
        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 404:
                // Page not found.
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error404");
                break;
            case 500:
                // Server error.
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error500");
                break;

            // Here you can handle Views to other error codes.
            // I choose a General error template  
            default:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
                break;
        }
    }

    // Pass exception details to the target error View.
    routeData.Values.Add("error", exception);

    // Clear the error on server.
    Server.ClearError();

    // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
    IController errorController = new ProjectName.WebSite.Controllers.ErrorController();
    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(
         new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));


}

private static bool RaiseErrorSignal(Exception e)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    if (context == null)
        return false;
    var signal = ErrorSignal.FromContext(context);
    if (signal == null)
        return false;
    signal.Raise(e, context);
    return true;
}
```

But Elmah cant log errors also i am raising error signal.

Comment: So, what is your question? All I see is a conclusion.

Comment: signal.Raise(e,context) doesn't work because when i go to /elmah.axd to see the exceptions, list is empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the problem, I missed a web.config section. I added "ErrorLog" module to `<system.webserver><modules>`.

I also need to add it to `<system.web><httpModules>`.

After adding, Elmah start to log errors.

Also I don't need to call ErrorSignal.Raise() method, Elmah can detect errors without signalling.

Comment: Another note: in my case it was the incorrect write permissions of the App_Data folder